# Ubuntu Touch – Flight mode still allowing connection

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Is this a known issue or do I need to log it in Launchpad? When I turn on flight mode, I can still connect to wi-fi on both my tablet and phone. When flight mode is set, surely it should turn off all connections (mobile data, Bluetooth & wi-fi) and not allow them to be connected individually, whilst still showing the flight mode symbol.

Comment: Same here with my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry this is not an issue.. It is always been like this.. With google's android too..
Sometime on a plane you may want to connect to the internal wifi service..

Bugs are many but more serious..

Comment: Probably the same in case of iPhone too: http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/97903

Comment: So you can have flight mode on and then turn on all connections such as bluetooth and wifi? Is it just that or does iy not seem right.

Comment: Yes ,of course  you can.

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1634273